# Python Unicode Output Format

Tags: python, tuples

In Python I pull in data via Win32Com as a tuple:

((u'**863579XK9**',),)

How can I parse this so that I am left with just 863579XK9 so I can write that to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = ((u'863579XK9',),)
print data[0][0] # prints "863579XK9"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print ((u'863579XK9',),)[0][0]
863579XK9
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a unicode string, you'd want to write it to a unicode encoded file:

```
import codecs
myfile = codecs.open('myfile.txt', encoding='utf8', mode='w')
data = ((u'863579XK9',),) 
myfile.write(data[0][0].encode('utf8'))
myfile.close()
```

See [Reading and Writing Unicode Data](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data) from the Python Unicode HOWTO.